# How can I get data from json with axios? (React)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

I'm trying to getting this JSON data

```
 {

    ID                string `json:"id"`
    Amount            int    `json:"amount"`
    Month             string `json:"month"`
    PayFailed         bool   `json:"pay_failed"`
}
```

and I wrote my code like this.

but I don't think this code can get data. I did console.log() but nothing come up. so 
I don't know how to check to get data successfully.

```
const Pay = props => {
  const { user, month,} = props;

  const classes = useStyles();

  const [Pay, setPay] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

   axios
    .get(https://test)
    .then(res => {
      setPay(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      alert("error");
    });

  }, [user]);

  return (
    <Table className={classes.table}>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell >date of pay</TableCell>
          <TableCell >amont</TableCell>
          <TableCell >pay</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {
          Pay.filter(pay => pay.month === month).map(pay => (
            pay.data.map((pay, index) => (
              <TableRow key={index}>
                <TableCell>{pay.DeletedAt}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{pay.amount}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{pay.pay_failed}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            )
          )))
        }
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  );
};

export default PayDone;
```

Does anyone know how to get it?

Comment: `res.data()` or more likely, `res.json()`, either **with** the parenthesis.

Comment: can you `console.log(res)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share some more detail? Like if you are having any errors or what the data looks like in your end, as we don't have access to the exact API. Add a console.log before `setPay(res.data);` and see what it returns.

Although not important in your case, Why are you doing the nested map? In your JSON schema, there is no object field. Instead all are atomic values.

```
Pay.filter(pay => pay.month === month).map((pay, index) => (
          <TableRow key={index}>
            <TableCell>{pay.DeletedAt}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{pay.amount}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{pay.pay_failed}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))
```